# Работа со строками в objective C

Tags: objective-c

Как проще всего узнать, заканчивается ли строка NSString определенной последовательностью символов?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

у NSString есть для этого метод

```
[str hasSuffix: @"suffix"];
```

и еще для проверки начинается ли последовательностью символов

```
[str hasPrefix: @"prefix"];
```

Answer (score 1):

Ищите подстроку в строке. Как-то так:

```
 NSString *str1 = @"Hello world";

    NSRange match;

    match = [str rangeOfString: @"world"];

    if (match.location == NSNotFound)
              NSLog (@"Match not found");
    else
              NSLog (@"match found at index %i", match.location);
```

Comment: так мы проверим, есть ли вообще эта строка... можно, конечно, поставить еще условие, что str1.length-match.location==str.lenght, но оказывается есть аналог endsWith/startsWith